# best way to have a fault tolerance server

Tags: linux, nginx, server

we have a laravel project on apache server in dedicated server with 16GB of ram and 4core cpu. our business has about 13000 records on database and many visitors in a day, also we have several task that run in midnight, when we monitor the host, many times in night the server is crashed and down and log shows out of memory, so I think about this and decided to have one more server and load balance between them when main server is crashed dns route to slave server that dont have any special code just a site with minimum requirements.
so which of these approach is good? I get one more robust server for our heavy task?? or set load balancing like such as I say, or have a one more server and move redis and mysql on it separately, how do I have a HA(high available) server?

Comment: First thing should be to find out why the server crashes at midnight. Out of memory? A certain job which causes problems? etc.. If you know where the crashes come from, then you probably also know how to best solve the problem.

Comment: yes, server crashes because out of memory